# Declaring a variable inside a method argument

Tags: java, println

Is it possible to declare a `String` object inside of a `.print()` statement in Java? For instance:

```
System.out.println(String str = "phew");
```

This does not work. So, does that mean that is it is "illegal". If it is possible, how do I do so? If it is in fact illegal, why is it illegal?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? (And don't try declaring a variable named `new`; that's a Java reserved word.)

Comment: No. Why? Becaue that's not how the language works, ignoring the fact that it would be utterly useless to do such a thing because of scope.

Comment: What is it you're actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I got my answer its "NO" Because its illegal.

Comment: @TedHopp i got it i will keep that `new` in mind.

Comment: All of the answers below have yet to state *why* this is not allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't **declare** variables, but you can **define** them:

```
String a; // declaration
System.out.println(a = "abc"); // allowed, defining and passing it as argument

System.out.println(String a = "abc"); // illegal
```

Comment: thanks This is all i wanted to know,whether this is  acceptable or not.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you mean

```
System.out.println(new String("new"));
```

but you can just do

```
System.out.println("new");
```

If you want to do more than this, can you say what it is exactly?

Answer (score 0):

you can assign variable inside println but you can not declare variable inside it.

```
String str;
System.out.println(str=new String("str")); // will work
```

*Assignment operator returns the thing it is assigning*

...

```
System.out.println(String Phew="phew"); // will not work
```

Comment: System.out.println(str=new String("str")); is there any going to code like this?

Comment: definition means, to give the actual value. Not to declare it.

Comment: @DipakChandranP I didn't get you. Kindly explain bit more.

Comment: Nothing special, i just thinking that if you can do str ="str",  why str=new String("str"), isn't both same and second one is little extra coding?

Comment: both are not `same str = "str"` this will create object in string pool and `str = new String("str");` will create object in heap space outside of string pool.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

String s;
System.out.println(s = "My name  is Dipak");

but i dont understand what sort of algorithm cause you implement something like this. :)
What exactly is , after each statement need a breaker, declaring variable is need before it used in other operation other than assignment.

Hope this will give you peace.